# How to get a list of deployments that only have a certain label in the spec section

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I know that I can perform this command to see all the pods that have a certain label : `kubectl get pods -l importance=normal`

Is there a command that would allow me to get the deployments that create the pods with the label `importance=normal`?

I want to find all deployments what have the label `importance=normal` found in the spec/template/metadata/labels (see my deployment yaml below).

I found this link(https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/list-all-running-container-images/#list-container-images-filtering-by-pod-label) and started to create the following command but I could not get it to work -

````
kubectl get deployments -namespace prod -o jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{"\n"}{.spec.template.metadata.labels}{":\t"}{", "}{end}{end}' |\ sort```
````

My deployment yaml looks like the following:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: "11"
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: service-qa
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: prod
    source: https://gitlab.services.com/service
  creationTimestamp: "2019-04-07T12:51:03Z"
  generation: 22
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    chart: service-0.1.0
  name: service-deployment
  namespace: qa
  resourceVersion: "577488289"
  uid: cd2fdeb4-5933-11e9-ad6d-02211a607320
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  replicas: 2
  revisionHistoryLimit: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: service-selector
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 0
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        kubectl.kubernetes.io/restartedAt: "2022-11-13T08:19:36-06:00"
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: service-selector
        importance: normal
        version: current
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest solution is probably using [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/). To get a list of Deployments that deploy Pods with the label `importance: normal`, you could do this:

```
kubectl get deploy -o json |
jq '.items[]|select(.spec.template.metadata.labels.importance == "normal")'
```

I would argue that you should rewrite your manifests so that the Deployment shares labels with the Pod so that you can just run:

```
kubectl get deploy -l importance=normal
```

That's much simpler. Using a tool like [kustomize](https://kustomize.io) can simplify the work involved in keeping these labels consistent.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks so much!!!
I will look into kustomize also